# How to echo a list into a textarea?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to echo a list into a textarea (to allow for simple copy and paste), I've got the list echoing out as flat html and its appearing as it should but I'd like it to be inside a textarea, here's what I've done so far...

```
<?php
include (ABSPATH.'/connect_include.php');
$AvDates = "SELECT * FROM DB_Available_Dates";
$AvDates = mysql_query($AvDates) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($AvDates) > 0){
?>
<input value=
<ul>
<?php
   while ($row_AvDates = mysql_fetch_assoc($AvDates)){ 
?>
      <li><?php echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']).' - '. htmlentities ($row_AvDates['the_days']); ?></li> 
<?php
   }      
?>
</ul> />

<?php
}

?>
```

This isn't working though - how can I make this work?

Comment: Why do you want to put a list into a textarea ?

Comment: The list is a list of dates that are to be copied and pasted into an email - I thought that this would be the easiest way to avoid html formatting - any other suggestions welcome :-)

Comment: A list inside a textarea is an invalid markup. You could either use newlines to signal the list, or use a js editor to add html capabilities

Comment: Ah, got it, new lines is probably the way to go then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this might help you:

```
<textarea>
<?php
$anyVar = "This\nis\na\nstring";
echo $anyVar;
?>
</textarea>
```

**Update:** Demo for your example

```html
<?php 
include (ABSPATH.'/connect_include.php'); 

$AvDates="SELECT * FROM DB_Available_Dates"; 
$AvDates=mysql_query($AvDates) or die(mysql_error()); 
if(mysql_num_rows($AvDates)>0)
{ 
?>
  <textarea>
  <?php 
    while ($row_AvDates=mysql_fetch_assoc($AvDates))
    {
      echo htmlentities($row_AvDates['Month']) . " - " . htmlentities ($row_AvDates['the_days']) . "\n"; 
    }
  ?>
  </textarea>    
<?php 
} 
?>
```

Comment: So, if I remove the ul and li tags and add "/n" at the end of the php echo line, it should return after each go round the loop?

Comment: yes if you concate `\n` at end of echo result  so while each loop it will be in a new line.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Comment: @dazzathedrummer check out the update, for your example.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help - I had to play about with rows= and cols= as the box was only one row high to start with but its all working as I wanted it now.